# How does a program "sit and wait" for an input while the program is running? (Conceptually)

Tags: operating-system

I am trying to understand conceptually how any program is "watching to" or "waiting for" user input while running and continues to run after input was given... or even, what does it mean "the program is running".
What does make the program sit and wait and not end the execution when the computer reads all lines of instructions? Is there a set of infinite loops that are waiting for some specific inputs?

I am a web developer (but I didn't study at a technical university) and I guess this concept is a pretty low level in informatics but I think it's very important for any kind of software developer to get better intuition in this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an infinite loop that is queried all the time by the program. On Windows, for example, there is the following in all programs (including web browsers):

```cpp
MSG msg = { };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

You have a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) that is filled with messages when an event happens. The dispatch message will dispatch the message to a generic procedure (a special function) that switches on the message to determine what it is and take action depending. A procedure can look like the following:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(
    HWND hwnd,        // Handle to window
    UINT uMsg,        // Message identifier
    WPARAM wParam,    // First message parameter
    LPARAM lParam)    // Second message parameter
{

    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            // Initialize the window.
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            // Paint the window's client area.
            return 0;

        case WM_SIZE:
            // Set the size and position of the window.
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            // Clean up window-specific data objects.
            return 0;

        //
        // Process other messages.
        //

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Every program needs to use the low-level API provided by Windows to draw or create windows. Otherwise, it doesn't have access to the hardware. Most often, the companies that create software will abstract away from this low-level API by using other higher level languages or by creating their own windowing framework that can then be used to create windows with widgets and other stuff.

Underneath, the GetMessage() function retrieves the messages available for the calling thread. Windows probably holds a message queue for every thread and, when GetMessage() is called, the queue is decremented by one message which is used to fill the `msg` structure.

It is really that simple.